# Prove derivative $1/x$ by induction

Tags: derivatives, induction

I'm trying to solve prove

$g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

$g^{(n)}(x)=\frac{(-1)^n(n!)}{x^{n+1}}$.

So for proving it I tried

**Base case:**

$g'(x)=\frac{-1}{x^2}=\frac{(-1)^1(1!)}{x^{1+1}}=\frac{-1}{x^2}$.

**Inductive step:**
$$ g^{(n)}(x)=\frac{(-1)^n(n!)}{x^{n+1}}$$

$$ g^{(n+1)}(x)=\frac{(-1)^{(n+1)} (n+1)\color{blue}{!}}{x^{n+2}}$$

So the way I was thinking about it is,

$g^n(x)'=g^{n+1}(x)$

but I can't continue from here:

$$g^{(n)}(x)'=\frac{n(-1)^{n-1}(n!)}{x^{n+1}}+\frac{(-1)^n-n!}{x^{2n+2}}.$$

Comment: You have $\frac{1}{x^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{x}\times \frac{1}{x^n}$. Then use Leibniz rule for the derivation of a product and the induction hypothesis...

Comment: You have an error in the inductive hypothesis. The correct is $g^{(n+1)}(x)=\frac{(−1)^{(n+1)}(n+1)!}{x^{n+2}}$.

Comment: I fixed it thanks Ramanujan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking a derivative with respect to $x$.  You seem to have use the product rule, but there are not two expressions containing $x$ multiplied here.

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} g^{(n)}(x) 
    &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left(  (-1)^n \frac{n!}{x^{n+1}} \right)  \\
    &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left(  (-1)^n n! x^{-(n+1)} \right)  \\
    &= (-1)^n n! (-(n+1)) x^{-(n+1) -1}  \\
    &= (-1)^{n+1} n! (n+1) x^{-(n+1) -1}  \\
    &= (-1)^{n+1} (n+1)! x^{-(n+1) -1}  \\
    &= (-1)^{n+1} \frac{(n+1)!}{x^{(n+1)+1}}  \\
    &= (-1)^{n+1} \frac{(n+1)!}{x^{n+2}}
\end{align*}

Comment: Sure there are two expressions. We have $\frac 1{x^{n+1}} = \frac1x\cdot \frac1{x^n}$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was using the product rule, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$$(g^{(n)})'=(-1)^{n}*n!*(x^{-(n+1)})'=(-1)^n*n!*(-(n+1)))(x^{-(n+2)}=(-1)^{(n+1)}*(n+1)!*x^{-(n+2)}$$
your derivative $$(g^{(n)})'$$ is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

It can be done in a much simpler way, if you know this elementary formula, parallel to $\;(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}$:
$$\biggl(\frac1{x^n}\biggr)'=-\frac n{x^{n+1}}.$$
Therefore
$$\Bigl(g^{(n)}(x)\Bigr)'=\biggl(\frac{(-1)^n n!}{x^{n+1}}\biggr)'=(-1)^n n!\biggl(\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}\biggr)'. $$
Can you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

For the inductive step we have

$$g^{n+1}(x)=(-1)^{n+1} \frac{(n+1)!}{x^{n+2}}=-\frac{n+1}{x}g^n(x)$$

which is true indeed

$$(g^n(x))'=\left(-\frac{n}{x}g^{n-1}(x)\right)'=\frac{n}{x^2}g^{n-1}(x)-\frac{n}{x}g^{n}(x)=-\frac{1}{x}g^{n}(x)-\frac{n}{x}g^{n}(x)=-\frac{n+1}{x}g^n(x)$$